# Use LIRC on Intel NUC (5th generation)

Tags: lirc, intel-nuc

I would like to use one of my old remote controls belonging to different devices for controlling the NUC5i7RYH.

After a BIOS update, in BIOS I can now choose between

- "Generic Remote Controller"
- "RC6 Remote Controller"
- "XBOX Remote Controller"

(Which setting is useful for arbitrary remote controls? *Generic?*)

and Ubuntu now, after the BIOS update, can list the IR device (`cat /proc/bus/input/devices`):

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=1050 Product=00c3 Version=0033
N: Name="Nuvoton w836x7hg Infrared Remote Transceiver"
P: Phys=nuvoton/cir0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pnp0/00:01/rc/rc0/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=100013
B: KEY=fff 0 200108fc32e 237605100000000 0 700158000 419200004001 8e968000000000 10000000
B: MSC=10
```

Output of `ir-keytable`:

```
Found /sys/class/rc/rc0/ (/dev/input/event6) with:
    Driver nuvoton-cir, table rc-rc6-mce
    Supported protocols: NEC RC-5 RC-6 JVC SONY SANYO LIRC RC-5-SZ SHARP XMP other 
    Enabled protocols: NEC RC-5 RC-6 JVC SONY SANYO LIRC RC-5-SZ SHARP XMP other 
    Name: Nuvoton w836x7hg Infrared Remote
    bus: 25, vendor/product: 1050:00c3, version: 0x0033
    Repeat delay = 500 ms, repeat period = 125 ms
```

`cat /dev/lirc0` returns rubbish if I press buttons on my remote controls, `cat /dev/input/event6` does the same. `irw` outputs nothing but mouse input when using `inputlirc`.

**Now I am at a loss making one of my remote controls work. What is the next step?**

Answer (score 1):

> `cat /dev/lirc0` returns rubbish if I press buttons on my remote controls

The "rubbish" is probably `mode2` space and pulse data, as described here:
http://lirc.org/html/lirc.html

You can verify that the data is space and pulse data by running the following command and then pressing buttons on your remote:
`mode2 -d /dev/lirc0`

To teach LIRC to understand a new remote control, try the following:
`irrecord -d /dev/lirc0 ~/lircd.conf`

To see a list of key names, run:
`irrecord --list-namespace`

I tried to learn a new remote with `irrecord` as described above, and it did not work for me.  But I believe the above is the standard procedure.  I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a NUC6CAY.

More info at these pages:
http://lirc.org/
https://learn.adafruit.com/using-an-ir-remote-with-a-raspberry-pi-media-center/lirc
https://learn.adafruit.com/using-an-ir-remote-with-a-raspberry-pi-media-center/using-other-remotes